# HTML toolbar button positioning

Tags: html, css, position

So here is my issue I have a logo on the nav bar of the website I'm developing and when i have the logo added, the text is not centered vertically, but when I remove the logo the text is centered.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.logohead {
  display: inline-block;
}
.links {
  color: white;
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: .8em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.links:hover {
  color: lightgray;
}
.navgation {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #33414a;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .8em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navgation">
  <li class="links" id="lgo">
    <img class="logohead" src="nl.png">
  </li>
  <li class="links">
    Hello World
  </li>
  <li class="links">
    Hello World2
  </li>
</ul>
```

Without logo:

[image: Without logo:]

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2ahjd8w/4/)

Comment: what about flexbox its great tool for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. One solution is using flexbox:

```
.navigation{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j2ahjd8w/6/

More solutions here: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.links`, like so:

```
.links {
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding: .8em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I've tried it in the provided fiddle and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use [flexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

```
.navgation {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: #33414a;
   width: 100%;
   padding: .8em;
}
```